# Fetch 5M URLs as fast as possible

Tags: scala, http, akka

I have a list of about **5.000.000 urls**, and I need to fetch them **as fast as possible**.

Right now I'm using Scala's Akka and [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) to execute HTTP requests. Architecture is pretty simple: I create single master actor and `N` workers (where `N` is normally between 100 and 1000) and send URLs to fetch to workers via `RoundRobinRouter`. However, on 8 core machine with 16Gb memory and 1Gbit/sec network it gives only ~250 requests/sec, with of three resources totally underutilized (CPU ~20%, network ~120Mbit/sec).

Am I doing something wrong? Should I use different tools or/and approach?

Comment: I wonder if the internet pipes are getting full.. and don't discount the latency to fetch the URLs as it can really add up. If a worker can only fetch 5 resources a second (~200ms each) then 100 could, at best, fetch 500/s.

Comment: @user2864740: yes, but then with 1000 workers I'd expect 5000/s, while it is still around 250. Also, channel (in Amazon EC2 instance) is underloaded, so I'm not sure what part of the network can be a bottleneck then.

Comment: Why do you need them so fast, anyway?  At 250/sec, you only need to spend 20,000 seconds which is a bit over 6 hours.  For 5 million URLs I'd think that was pretty good time.

Comment: @RexKerr: if this project succeeds, next step will be to increase number of URLs up to 250M and run the scan every couple of days, which means that we need at least 1-2k requests/sec. Anyway, I'm trying to find what binds the maximum number requests given that neither CPU nor network are utilized fully.

Comment: That's solvable by simply having more servers in different locations, no?

Comment: @RexKerr: I thought about it as a last resort, but if I can get more from a single machine, it will save both - money and development time.

Comment: At some point won't you hit a limit of open connections on the network?

Comment: @m-z: I've already increased limit for the number of open files, are there any other limits I can/should increase?

Comment: Maybe you are hitting the maxConnections limit of AsyncHttpClient. Are you using a custom config? And what provider, Netty?

Comment: @Bilk: yes, I use Netty at the backend and custom config: max number of connections per host is set to 10 (I assume even 1 should be enough since every time I connect to a different host) and max total number of connections is set to 100k. But even processing batch of 10k URLs is pretty slow, so it's unlikely that I reach this limit. Is there anything else I can tune up in `AsyncHttpClient`?

Comment: What about tuning the Akka dispatcher? Did you give it a try?

Comment: @Bilk: I tried different parameters, but without any change. Moreover, I've got almost the same results with old plain thread pool (500 threads) and even [different programming language](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/Requests.jl/issues/61). The picture is always the same: most requests get executed very quickly, and then strange delays start happening. I blame some low-level buffers or limits (e.g. number of open connections), but I have no more time to investigate it.